# Windows Server - Visual Studio Dev Machine for Contractors

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services, visual-studio

I am setting up a windows server machine with visual studio and multiple users.

All users will be working on the same project on different user accounts.

1) Will it be possible to have all users running in isolation and running a project on the same port?

2) When I have a user profile setup with all tools installed, what's the easiest way to copy user profile and create a new user based off that?

Comment: Would azure remoteapps be a better alternative?

Answer (score 2):

1. No.
2. Use the System Control Panel to copy user profiles.

Remote Desktop Servers are not good developer environments, unless each developer gets their own Remote Desktop Server.